# What does TAB do in vim?

Tags: vim

I normally don't write tabs, so I mapped `<TAB>` to `<ESC>` in insert mode so that it's faster to leave insert mode. However, when I accidentally press TAB in normal mode, it jumps to some location in the file, without saving the jump location. I first suspected that a plugin is doing that, but I find no mapping for TAB in normal mode. Even explicitly unmapping it doesn't help, so it must be a built-in command. What does it do, why isn't this jump saved to history, and how do I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the built-in [`:help CTRL-I`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#CTRL-I); `<C-I>` and `<Tab>` are the same in (G)Vim. That command is the opposite of `<C-O>`; it goes to a newer position in the jump list. You don't see the "saving to history", because it operates on existing jumps.

If you don't want any action on Tab in normal mode, just put

```
:nnoremap <Tab> <Nop>
```

into your `~/.vimrc`; [`:help <Nop>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3CNop%3E).

Comment: If I remap <Tab> to <Nop>, then I also lose <C-I>. Is there no way to decouple the two?

Comment: Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it do, why isn't this jump saved to history, and how do I disable it?

"Tab" (or `<C-I>`, which is really the same thing) goes forward through the `jumplist` ("undo" for `<C-O>`), so it's either no-op, or still there's nothing to save ;-) To see the embedded help topic use `:h <tab>`

If you really want to disable it, just remap it:

```
nnoremap <tab> <nop>
```

Comment: I like how we came up with nearly identical answers at the same time :-)

Comment: @IngoKarkat Me too ;-)